# Why do display: block and display: flex render the same element with a different height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a div with a span inside. And I'm setting display:block or display:flex on the div, and a small font-size on the span. Surprisingly, this is giving different heights on the div. See the example.

If I set the smaller font-size on the body or div then the height of both is equal. But if I set the smaller font-size on the span like in the example, then the divs get different heights. How come? And can I do anything about it?

```css
span {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

div {
  border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: block;">
  <span>test text 1</span>
</div>

<div style="display: flex;">
  <span>test text 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In a [***block formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting), the `line-height` property makes a difference.

This is because `line-height` establishes the minimum height for inline-level elements and line boxes inside block-level containers.

In a block formatting context a `span` is an inline-level element and `line-height` applies.

In the code sample, any font size on the `span` below 1rem will change the `font-size`, but not the `line-height`, which remains fixed. That's what you're seeing with `font-size: .8rem`. The height of the `div` doesn't change. And it won't change unless the font size exceeds 1rem.

In a [***flex formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers), the `span` is a flex item. A flex item is always a block-level element (regardless of the element type). Flex items are "blockified", according to the [flexbox spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items). Because there are no inline-level elements, `line-height` doesn't apply.

Also, an initial setting of a flex container is `align-items: stretch`. This means that the `span` sets the height of the container.

**In summary**, with `display: block` the `line-height` keeps the div height fixed. With `display: flex`, there is no `line-height` interference and the div tracks the height of the span freely.

One solution: Add `display: block` to the `span`, which eliminates the `line-height` issue.

Comment: Also default value in the 2nd axis (vertical, by default) of Flexbox things is `align-items: stretch` as seen in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kvbL49gt/ (maybe that's what you're updating but I won't know till tomorrow morning ^^)