# How to make sure div that contains span has size of div

Tags: html, css

I would like to make sure that *div* that contains *span* is the size of the *span*, regardless of font used in *span*.

Simple example:

```css
    .boxName {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid yellow;
        min-height: 0%;
    }
    
    span {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;    
        font-size: 1vw;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="boxName">
     <span>title</span>
    </div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vdp51ae9/15/)

If you remove *font-size* from *span*, you will get *div* perfectly fit to *span*. Modifying *font-size* of *span* changes size of the *div* in not understandable (for me) manner.

Any suggestions how to make sure that *div* is the size of *span*?

Thank you!
Marcin

Comment: font-size increases the content height and width therefore the parent expands simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add font-size to `div` instead of `span`

```css
.boxName {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  min-height: 0%;
  font-size: 1vw;
}

span {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="boxName">
  <span>title</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `width:min-content;` to your div

```
.boxName {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    min-height: 0%;
    width:min-content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you're using the `block` value on the `display` attribute.

change to `inline-block`:

```
.boxName {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    min-height: 0%;
}

span {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;    
    font-size: 1vw;
}
```

```css
.boxName {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  min-height: 0%;
}

span {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxName">
  <span>title</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set     `display: block;` to `span` and     `width: fit-content;`

```css
.boxName {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    min-height: 0%;
}

span {
    width: fit-content;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1vw;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxName">
 <span>title</span>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: @VXp funny... but I lolll to myself... I really like to help people... do you follow me ;)

Comment: @VXp but like in developing you have to be consistent

Comment: I can see that, but do you have to write that every single time? I think it's pretty obvious. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The challenge with this solution is that after changing span's display to block the whole row (or div) is black - in my example only the text's background is black.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex;` on box div

```css
 
.boxName {
display: flex;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid yellow;
min-height: 0%;
}

span {
background-color: black;
color: white;    
font-size: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxName">
 <span>title</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` for div `.boxName`, Then it will be working perfectly. And also no need for `min-height: 0%;`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xa0L7tr6/)

You can get more idea from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47439859/3098803