# What's the difference between using width and min-width in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-image

**Background**

I want to display the icon through `background-image`, but if the text is too long, it will be obscured by text.

```css
.box {
  display : inline-flex;
}

.box:before {
  content : '';
  background-image: url('https://imgur.com/TCc5A1P');
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure harum commodi totam sit, natus dolore reiciendis. Nihil possimus, magni praesentium molestias ab vel dolorum rem. Eos autem saepe magnam pariatur.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi 
</div>
```

[image]

---

**Question**

When I use `min-width` instead of `width` or use `inline-block` for `.box`, it will work. Can anyone tell me why `min-width` or `inline-block` works?

[image]

*use `min-width` instead of `width`*

```css
.box {
  display : inline-flex;
}

.box:before {
  content : '';
  background-image: url('https://imgur.com/TCc5A1P');
  min-width: 60px;
  /* width: 60px; */
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure harum commodi totam sit, natus dolore reiciendis. Nihil possimus, magni praesentium molestias ab vel dolorum rem. Eos autem saepe magnam pariatur.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi 
</div>
```

--

use `inline-block` for `.box`

```css
.box {
  /* display : inline-flex; */
  display : inline-block;
}

.box:before {
  content : '';
  background-image: url('https://imgur.com/TCc5A1P');
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure harum commodi totam sit, natus dolore reiciendis. Nihil possimus, magni praesentium molestias ab vel dolorum rem. Eos autem saepe magnam pariatur.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi 
</div>
```

Comment: `min-width` is the minimum width the element. It can be larger than the specified value if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use `min-width` instead of `width` or use `inline-block` for `.box`, it will work. Can anyone tell me why `min-width` or `inline-block` works?

---

### `min-width`

Sets the minimum width of an element.

---

### `width`

Sets the width of an element.

---

### `display: inline-flex` (and `flex`)

An initial setting on flex items is `flex-shrink: 1`. This means that flex items can shrink below their defined `width` / `height` to prevent their overflow of the container. In order to prevent this behavior, *you need to disable `flex-shrink`*.

For example:

```
.box::before {
  width: 60px;
  flex-shrink: 0; <------ add this to your code
  content : '';
     ...
     ...
     ...
}
```

Or, for a cleaner version (which is also [recommended by the flexbox spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components)), use this:

```
.box::before {
  flex: 0 0 60px; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
  content : '';
     ...
     ...
     ...
}
```

Note that `flex-shrink` applies to `width` and `height`, but not to `min-width` and `min-height`. By disabling `flex-shrink` on an element, you are effectively establishing its minimum length.

For example:

```
width: 60px;
flex-shrink: 0;
```

is equivalent to:

```
min-width: 60px;
```

For a more complete explanation, see *"The `flex-shrink` factor"* section in my answer here:

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

---

### `display: inline-block` (and `block`)

`flex-shrink` (described above) does not apply in a block formatting content.

---

### revised code

```css
.box {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.box::before {
  flex: 0 0 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure harum
  commodi totam sit, natus dolore reiciendis. Nihil possimus, magni 
  praesentium molestias ab vel dolorum rem. Eos autem saepe magnam 
  pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Quasi
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Width Property will change the horizontal image dimensions to the pixels you have defined (In your case 60px).  Width = 60px
2. Min-Width will make sure that horizontal image width is greater that or equal to the pixel you have defined. Width >= 60px.

The ouput that you see in your case is because the image is taking its original dimensions. ie some value greater tha 60px.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I update my question, because I still confused  about `min-height`, if I change the `.box` display to `inline-block`, I don't need to use `min-width` instead of `width`

Comment: @ChunbinLi, when you set display to inline-block, your width is not respected. so It defaults to your actual image size. Have a look into this link for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800125/why-does-inline-block-automatically-adjust-its-width-according-to-its-childs-w

Answer (score -1):

**width:**

The width CSS property specifies the width of the content area of an element. The content area is inside the padding, border, and margin of the element.

**min-width:**

The min-width CSS property is used to set the minimum width of a given element. It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming smaller than the value specified for min-width.

**max-width:**

The max-width CSS property is used to set the maximum width of a given element. It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming larger than the value specified for max-width.

Please visit [Info Source](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/minmaxwidth-vs-width) for more info.

**Edited**

this also apply with height,

to make it simpler and more general

`something = 10px;`

the value is neither less nor more then 10px.

`min-something = 10px;`

the minimum value **can't below** the  given property value. 
E.g.= 10px, 11px, 20px, 300px is above minimum level so it is accepted. So the image cant be lower then 10px in resolution.

`max-something = 10px;`

the maximum value **can't exceed or above** the given property value.
E.g.= 9px, 8px, 5px, 0px is below maximum level so it is accepted. So the image cant be higher then 10px in resolution.

**Below is few example**

**min width and height is 100px**

```css
.box {
  /*display : inline-flex;*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.box:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://smartlogic.io/images/brand-assets/smartlogic-seal-teal-100.png');
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure harum commodi totam sit, natus dolore reiciendis. Nihil possimus, magni praesentium molestias ab vel dolorum rem. Eos autem saepe magnam pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Quasi

  <br> please note that image is 100px *100px
</div>
```

**min width and height is 60px**

```css
.box {
  /*display : inline-flex;*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.box:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://smartlogic.io/images/brand-assets/smartlogic-seal-teal-100.png');
  min-width: 60px;
  min-height: 60px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure harum commodi totam sit, natus dolore reiciendis. Nihil possimus, magni praesentium molestias ab vel dolorum rem. Eos autem saepe magnam pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Quasi
  <br> please note that image is 100px * 100px
</div>
```

**width and height is 60px**

```css
.box {
  /*display : inline-flex;*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.box:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://smartlogic.io/images/brand-assets/smartlogic-seal-teal-100.png');
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure harum commodi totam sit, natus dolore reiciendis. Nihil possimus, magni praesentium molestias ab vel dolorum rem. Eos autem saepe magnam pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Quasi
  <br> please note that image is 100px * 100px
</div>
```

**width and height is 100px**

```css
.box {
  /*display : inline-flex;*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.box:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://smartlogic.io/images/brand-assets/smartlogic-seal-teal-100.png');
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure harum commodi totam sit, natus dolore reiciendis. Nihil possimus, magni praesentium molestias ab vel dolorum rem. Eos autem saepe magnam pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Quasi
  <br> please note that image is 100px * 100px
</div>
```

**Also note that**

in your case,
when you use max-width you need to define the min-width as well. 
min-width will give you the space form image to show.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I update my question, because I still confused  about `min-height`, if I change the `.box` display to `inline-block`, I don't need to use `min-width` instead of `width`

Comment: @ChunbinLi You can check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439665/why-do-display-block-and-display-flex-render-the-same-element-with-a-different
hope this will help your more.