# Uneven radio buttons on Safari Mobile

Tags: html, css

**Problem**

Uneven radio button size on Safari iphone devices, first radio button is small as compare to second one

In other browsers for iphone devices it is fine.

**Code**

```
<div style="border: thin solid lightgray; border-top-left-radius: 2%; border-top-right-radius: 2%; border-bottom-right-radius: 2%; border-bottom-left-radius: 2%;">
        <br>
        <label style="font-weight: bold; display: contents;">Return options: </label>
        <div class="radio center-label">
            <input type="radio" id="0" name="radio" value="0" style="margin: 1%;">
            <label for="0" style="white-space: pre-line;">Purchase a FedEx return label - $9.50. Price will be deducted from your refund. We will email your return label within 15 minutes</label>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="radio center-label">
            <input type="radio" id="1" name="radio" value="1" style="margin: 1%;">
            <label for="1" style="white-space: pre-line;">Ship it yourself</label>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>


.center-label {
 display: flex;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-right: 15%;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .center-label {
       display: flex;
       margin-left: 3%;
       margin-right: 3%;
    }
}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

When I am removing the `centre-label`, uneven behaviour is fixed, I don't know why.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

when you add flex to the container, the children elements will share the space. and the first label text is longer, so this label take more space than the other label. you can set fixed width with flex css look here: [css tricks flex box guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Changing `display: block` fixed the issue.

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
.center-label {
   display: block;
   margin-left: 3%;
   margin-right: 3%;
}
}
```

After going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47439859/7808346), I concluded that: In `display: block` line-height of the div is fixed while in `display: flex` line-height is variable i.e. not fixed.

Is this conclusion correct or I've made it wrong, in case of wrong anybody can give the right source from where I can understand this concept completely.

TIA